# Trigger drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with an `input type="file"`. I have a `div` surrounding the `input`. I then set the `input` to `display:none`. In JavaScript, I set that when you select the `div`, the `input` gets selected.

That all works nice and dandy, but how can I make it that when you drag a file onto the `div`, the `input` should trigger a `drop` event?

So here's how I would do the `click` event:

```
$('#target').click();
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
$('#target').drop();
```

#### JSFiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#browseFileDiv').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('input[type="file"]').click();
  });

  $('#browseFileDiv input').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
#browseFileDiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#browseFileDiv > input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="uploadform">
  <div id="browseFileDiv">
    <input id="openFile" name="img" type="file" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Check out this example http://jsfiddle.net/davidfstr/y2y50222/3/

Comment: That works. You can post it as an answer

Comment: @Horay But that does not dispatch the drop event, isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: @godzsa You're right, but it achieves what I wanted. It doesn't answer the question but achieves what I want. If someone has a better approach then I'm all ears! :)

Comment: @Cory It only works if the input is there, right? Meaning I can't make it display:none. Correct?

Comment: @Horay well the link posted by Corey is an example of what PHPglue suggested as an answer. You can accept that I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to wrap the `<input type="file">` with a div around it and then with javscript trigger the `.click()` event for that input file if you click the div, make a `<label>` for this input file and style it, thus you can trigger the click event with HTML only without the need for javascript:

```
<label for="openFile" id="browseFile"></label>
<input id="openFile" name="img" type="file">
```

**Updated:** Then, as in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/9uwaouaf/) the problem is that you need to `return false;` for the `ondragover` and `ondrop` events

```
var browseFile = document.getElementById('browseFile');
browseFile.ondragover = function () {
    return false;
};
browseFile.ondrop = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();
    var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log(files);
    return false;
};
```

** *Note that the above works for multiple files as well.*

Resource: http://html5doctor.com/drag-and-drop-to-server/

Comment: In your example, when you drag and drop an image, it opens a dialog to choose an image

Comment: Sure, because of this `document.getElementById('openFile').click();` just showing an example

Comment: to capture the file you need this `var files = event.dataTransfer.files;`

Comment: Okay. Let me check it out.

Comment: I didn't understand why do I need to return false?

Comment: for the `ondragover` event if you don't `return false` the browser will behave as it should by default and load that image in the browser window so we return false to prevent it from doing this, but for the `ondrop` it is optional

Comment: Got it. Also, I tried creating an alert when the user uploads an image, but it didn't work http://jsfiddle.net/9uwaouaf/3/

Comment: Check this, it will alert a phrase as well as the file name http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/9uwaouaf/4/

Comment: How can I get an alert when you click on it? (If it's possible to please show me in JQuery. Thanks)

Comment: Here you go, http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/9uwaouaf/5/ btw you can use raw javascript and jquery together

Comment: Thanks I meant onchange

Answer (score -1):

`$('#browseFileDiv').on('drop', function(){/* code here */})` is probably what you're looking for.

You probably really want to use [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/droppable). Click the `view source` button.

Comment: I think he wants to trigger the `drop` event on `input` when `dragenter` is fired, but I don't know yet how to achieve that

Comment: I am trying to get the drop event triggered, but I had no luck yet

Comment: Probably need to use `jQuery UI`'s Droppable  Widget along with Draggable Widget. `DroppableInstance.drop(function(){})`